# Apache commons configuration reading properties in the format a.<no>.b

Tags: java, configuration-files, apache-commons

I have a properties file that says

```
window.1.height=100
window.1.width=80

window.2.height=50
window.2.width=30

window.3.height=150
window.3.width=100
```

I am using the `PropertiesConfiguration` class and reading the properties.
How can I know the count of windows in the properties. Is therea pattern search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use something like

```
int i = 0;
String val;
for(;;) {
  val = props.get("foo" + i);
  if (null == val) {
     break;
  }
  //process val
}
```

This places the constraint that the counter values must be contiguous.

Comment: That works, but i'm wondering if I can determine the length from the commons config itself. Eventually have to loop though

Comment: I haven't ever found a way to do that so I'll be watching to see if anyone else has had better luck too.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you can do if you have any control over the properties file itself. If you are locked into that format, I don't believe there is anything you can do.

However, if you are not locked into that format, here are a couple of solutions:

**XML Configuration**

Change from a properties file to an XML file format. Something like this:

```
<windows>
  <window>
    <width>80</width>
    <height>100</height>
  </window>
  <window>
    <width>30</width>
    <height>50</height>
  </window>
  <window>
    <width>100</width>
    <height>150</height>
  </window>
</windows>
```

Then use [XMLConfiguration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/howto_xml.html) instead of PropertiesConfiguration. You could then call

```
config.getList("windows").size()
```

to get the count of windows.

**Properties Configuration**

Your other option, which still involves a properties file, is a little bit more contrived. Your properties file would change to look like this:

```
window.height=100
window.width=80

window.height=50
window.width=30

window.height=150
window.width=100
```

Then to get the number of windows you would call

```
config.getList("window.height").size();
```

However, using this method, you would have to change how you retrieve the values. For example, in order to get the width and height of the second window, you would use this:

```
config.getInteger("window.width(1)");
config.getInteger("window.height(1)");
```

Using parens, you can access an individual element of a list, using zero-based indicies. It is a little more difficult to understand, but it would work.

Answer (score 0):

The api has it already onboard. See [Configuration#subset](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/javadocs/v1.10/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration.html#subset(java.lang.String))